# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'detect_intent'

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

Software/Package - Dialogflow

I'm trying to run the code from line 34 - 61 as shown in https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/blob/master/samples/detect_intent_texts.py

However, I get the issue in line :

```
response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
```

I tried reinstalling the library, but the error persisted, even after trying on another computer.

```
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

for text in texts:
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    # ERROR IN THE FOLLOWING LINE
    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)

    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name,
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
```

Any suggestions on how I may resolve this?

Here is the entire error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-15e77dd35618> in <module>
     10     query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
     11 
---> 12     response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
     13 
     14     print('=' * 20)

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dialogflow_v2/gapic/sessions_client.py in detect_intent(self, session, query_input, query_params, input_audio, retry, timeout, metadata)
    255             self._inner_api_calls[
    256                 'detect_intent'] = google.api_core.gapic_v1.method.wrap_method(
--> 257                     self.transport.detect_intent,
    258                     default_retry=self._method_configs['DetectIntent'].retry,
    259                     default_timeout=self._method_configs['DetectIntent']

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'detect_intent'
```

Comment: Is this the exact code which is failing? Looks OK from here.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact code. 
The code seems fine, but when I try running it, the error pops up.